# Remove values in a cell based on a string part

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in Excel that contains a series of comma delimited values.  The number of values in each row is different and the values I'm searching for can be in different positions within the cell.  I would like to remove some of those values based on based on a string part.

Example cell:

```
2006CE3, 2007CE3, 2012CE1, 2012CE3, 2013CE1, 2013CE3, 2014CE2, 2015CE3, 2016CE2, 2019FA, 2020SP
```

Specifically, remove all values containing "CE".  In the example above, I would like to remove `2006CE3, 2007CE3, 2012CE1, 2012CE3, 2013CE1, 2013CE3, 2014CE2, 2015CE3, 2016CE2,` and leave `2019FA, 2020SP`

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

To do this with a formula one will need TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CE",FILTERXML("<z><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</y><y>")&"</y></z>","//y"))),"",TRIM(FILTERXML("<z><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</y><y>")&"</y></z>","//y"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Woah, I was thinking it'd have to be some kind of array formula.  What are the `<y>` and `<z>` bits?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this formula solution of which using TEXTJOIN function available for Office 365

In `B2`, enter formula :

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,", ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[not(contains(.,'CE'))]"),0))
```

[image]

Comment: I've been using `FILTERXML` but never been able to apply it to it's fullest. This is neat! ++

Comment: I need to do more research on xpath.

Comment: @ScottCraner, For your information, the newest XPath version is 3.1, but Filterxml function only support version 1.0